# Change the value of a cell after some selected rows in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a datagridview (dataGridViewYoungLearnersEggrafes), 4 textboxes(txtboxSlot, txtboxDurationExam, txtboxBreakFrom, txtboxBreakTo) and 1 toolstriptextbox(TimeSpeakingToolStripMenuItem. I put an integer ex. 3 in txtboxSlot, an integer ex.20 in txtboxDurationExam , a time in txtboxBreakFrom ex.12:50 and a time in txtboxBreakTo ex. 13:05. after that i select all the rows from the grid and i put a time in TimeSpeakingToolStripMenuItem which is textbox.
When i press enter key i want to put the value of TimeSpeakingToolStripMenuItem to the first 3 rows of the grid and the next 3 rows will take the same value + txtboxDurationExam etc, when the rows are going to take values between the txtboxBreakFrom and txtboxBreakTo it wil put the txtboxBreakTo for that 3 rows and it will continue with same way like before. So far i have write the code below, and the thing that it does is to give the value of the TimeSpeakingToolStripMenuItem and the next row takes that value + txtboxDurationExam.
Can someon helps me out?
I wil appreciate any help.

```
private void toolStripTextBoxoraSpeaking_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (toolStripTextBoxoraSpeaking.Text != "")
                {
                    TimeSpan timeSpeaking = TimeSpan.Parse(toolStripTextBoxoraSpeaking.Text);
                    int DurationExam = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxDiarkeiaExetasis.Text.ToString());
                    int slot = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxSlot.Text.ToString());
                    TimeSpan DialimaApo = TimeSpan.Parse(txtboxDialimaApo.Text);
                    TimeSpan DialimaEos = TimeSpan.Parse(txtboxDialimaEos.Text);
                    TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, DurationExam, 0);

                    Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridViewYoungLearnersEggrafes.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

                    if (selectedRowCount > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
                        {
                            dataGridViewYoungLearnersEggrafes.SelectedRows[i].Cells["timeSpeakingDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = timeSpeaking;//Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                            timeSpeaking += duration;
                        }
                    }

                    BSProgrammaExetaseonYoungLearnersEggrafes.EndEdit();
                    programmaExetaseonYoung_Learners_Starters_MoversFlyersEggrafesTableAdapter.Connection = MyConn;
                    programmaExetaseonYoung_Learners_Starters_MoversFlyersEggrafesTableAdapter.Update(DSPerioxes_EidoiEksetaseonNew.ProgrammaExetaseonYoung_Learners_Starters_MoversFlyersEggrafes);
                    toolStripTextBoxoraSpeaking.Clear();
                    MessageBox.Show("Οι εγγραφές που επιλέξατε ενημερώθηκαν!", "Ενημέρωση!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Παρακαλώ πληκτρολογήστε Ώρα Speaking!", "Ενημέρωση!");
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: I am guessing if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you may find your problem. Currently it is not clear what you are asking. In addition, posting code that is only a partial picture of the actual question is not going to attract much help from others. You should clearly state what the problem is and post code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: One thing I am guessing you may be missing is the part about the “selected” rows. This is a risky thing to do considering the user could select rows in any order and not necessarily in a consecutive order. Are you anticipating this? In addition, when the grid “adds” rows to the “selected” rows collection, it does so by adding the “last” selected row to the “top” of the collection. Therefore, the “selected” rows collection will be in reverse order of what the user actually selected. Using your code, the values will start at the bottom and increase upward.